# groupadd: group 'terminal' already exists in Linux

Tags: linux, group

I have created a group called "terminal" using `groupadd terminal` and when I list out the groups using `groups` command it will not show the newly created group name in the output but if I add the same group again it gives me `groupadd: group 'terminal' already exists` error message but the group name exists in `/etc/group` file. Why I am not able to see the newly added group while running `groups` command ? ( I have tried them in Ubuntu Linux )

Answer (score 3):

The command `groups` doesn't show you all groups, it just lists all the groups the user is a member of.

So if you created a group, but your user isn't a member, `groups` won't show it. And if you try to create the group again you get the error message.